# AppService access restrictions and access from Release Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

As part of my deployment I would like to call some endpoint in my application to smoke test it.
But we are using Access Restrictions and calls from Azure Devops Release Pipeline are rejected.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after asking question I noticed there is new option in Preview in Access Restrictions page in Azure portal.

[image]

With this rule Azure Devops will be able to reach application endpoints.

Or using Powershell

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule
  -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup"
  -WebAppName "webapi"
  -Priority 65000
  -ServiceTag Azurecloud
  -Action Allow
```

In future you should be able to use `AzureDevOps` service tag, but looks like it's not supported in Preview - [Set a service tag-based rule (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#set-a-service-tag-based-rule-preview)

Comment: `AzureDevOps` now appears in the list but does not work for me. `AzureCloud` works fine.

Comment: "AzureDevOps tag will not permit you to allow releases from Microsoft hosted Azure DevOps agents, as these are not part of the AzureDevOps IP range (it only covers the AzureDevOps service itself and not the agents)." Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15214